# Como añadir una imagen al fondo de un titulo? (y como vincular CSS con HTML)

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title> Community of Cheats | Free Cheats and Injectors. </title> <!--Titulo de la box de arriba--> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<meta name="description" content="We offer the best free cheats out there. On our site you will find all free cheats checked by our team. Be a member."> <!--Titulo que aparece en la descripcion en la busqueda de la pagina-->
</head>
<body>
<title>Imagenes de fondo</title>
<div class="image-fondo cabecera">
      <h1><p align="center">Community of Cheats | Free Cheats and Injectors</p></h1> <!--Titulo en la web-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Necesito saber que tengo que hacer para añadir el fondo que quiero, me vais diciendo que tengo que hacer para ponerlo, gracias.

Comment: El nombre que uso para el titulo y asi es un example

Comment: Lo primero recomendado por favor es leer [ask] y realizar el [tour]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, agrega tu css sobre `image-fondo` y explica más detalladamente tú problema, y luego lo que deseas lograr.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente, puedes usar estilos `CSS` para conseguir una imagen de fondo, así:

```css
.cabecera {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1600/100');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title> Community of Cheats | Free Cheats and Injectors. </title>
  <!--Titulo de la box de arriba-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
  <meta name="description" content="We offer the best free cheats out there. On our site you will find all free cheats checked by our team. Be a member.">
  <!--Titulo que aparece en la descripcion en la busqueda de la pagina-->
</head>

<body>
  <title>Imagenes de fondo</title>
  <div class="image-fondo cabecera">
    <h1>
      Community of Cheats | Free Cheats and Injectors
    </h1>
    <!--Titulo en la web-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

En la propiedad `background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1600/100');` pones la ruta de tu imagen.

También puedes centrar el texto desde el `CSS` y evitar los estilos en línea `text-align: center;`. Fíjate que no es necesario usar una etiqueta `<p>` para lograrlo.

El código `CSS` lo puedes tener:

- Como atributo en cada elemento del DOM (no recomendado)

```
<div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1600/100');"></div>
```

- Dentro de las etiquetas `<head></head>`, entre etiquetas `<style></style>`

```
<head>
  <style>
  .cabecera {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1600/100');
  }
  </style>
</head>
<div class="cabecera">...</div>
```

- En una hoja de estilos independiente de tu `HTML` y lo puedes vincular con la etiqueta `link` (recomendado), tal como lo tienes aquí:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
```

**PD:** *No debes hacer varias preguntas en una ya que va en contra de las normas de la comunidad. Sigue las recomendaciones que te han dejado en los comentarios. Cuando edites tu pregunta, déjame un comentario para descartar mi voto de cierre.*